# How can I identify the pixel with the maximum value in a grid?

Tags: arcobjects, raster, vba, vb.net, vbscript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the locations of the highest values in a raster?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13289/how-to-find-the-locations-of-the-highest-values-in-a-raster)

How can I identify the pixel with the maximum value in a grid and get its coordinates? Any VBA code please?

Comment: The code [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/11988/59) could be modified to do this. For vba, see [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=995&t=58550#147741) and [this](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=63363#162894).

Comment: Ok Kirk thanks. Although I have no experience with raster programming tasks I will study these examples hoping will help me. Any more problem specific information is also welcomed.